# Android - application crashes on 2nd start (FragmentManager issue)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I start my application first time, everything works clean. I finish my activity using `finish().`

After this, I start my application again and it crashes with this log:

```
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fileexplorermanager/com.landa.fileexplorermanager.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1327)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1338)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at com.landa.features.BrowseHandler.populateContent(BrowseHandler.java:137)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at com.landa.features.BrowseHandler.openFile(BrowseHandler.java:98)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at com.landa.fileexplorermanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-19 15:33:16.652: E/AndroidRuntime(1859):     ... 11 more
```

It appears the problem is populateContent() function which calls FragmentManager's commit - that's the line it's failing on:

```
public void populateContent(File f)
{
    FragmentTransaction transaction = ac.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ContentFragment cf = new ContentFragment(ctx, ac, this, f);

    transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, cf);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    updateShownPath(f.getPath());
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Now, I have no idea why would an application work fine the first time, then finish(), then crash on 2nd start.

Any hints?

Note: I do have one fragment in FragmentManager before finishing the app (ALWAYS) - that's the home fragment.

This is the onCreate():

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initialiseApplication();

    browseHandler.openFile(new File(BrowseHandler.current_path));

}
```

Comment: You can post your `onCreate` and `onPause/onResume` if available. Because this error seems related

Comment: onCreate() only calls the above function and I don't have onPause / onResume.

Comment: Is this `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` the first line in your `onCreate()` ?

Comment: Yep. I posted the onCreate() above.

Comment: Where you define the `ctx` object. It seems the reason for this error that you are calling `commit` in a context that already got destroyed i.e. `Activity` that finished

Comment: Yeah. I solved it by moving the task into back with moveTaskToBack() instead of finishing() it. If you want, you can write up an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the reason for this error that you are calling `commit` in a context that already got destroyed i.e. Activity that finished.

Make sure that your `ctx` variable refers to an active `Activity`. Alternatively, you might want to keep your `Activity` in the background instead of manually finishing it.